# C# does var have a strong type?

Tags: c#, runtime, type-conversion, var, rtti

As at the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

...An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, ***but the compiler determines the type***...

But I have such piece of code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null) Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in Session)
        {
            sb.Append("Session Parameter: [");
            sb.Append(item);
            sb.Append("]<p />Guid Value: [");
            sb.Append(Session[item] + "]");
        }

        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
```

I'm getting such error in Visual Studio:

***Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' for the line:***

```
 sb.Append(Session[item] + "]");
```

But `item` is identifying at runtime as a `string` type as I looked in the debugger.

When I have read about `var` at msdn/in books I thought that `var` doesn't relate to RTTI-stuff. Compilers just changes the variable with this implicitly type on explicitly type like `string, int` etc at compile time.

Why did I catch such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `Session` is a [HttpSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) implements `IEnumerable` (though the same would happen if it implemented `IEnumerable<object>`), so your `var` gets mapped by the compiler into:

```
  foreach (object item in Session)
  {
```

In this case, this is likely `IEnumerable`, so you would need to specify the type explicitly in the `foreach`:

```
  foreach (string item in Session)
  {
```

This is allowed with `foreach` for non-generic `IEnumerable` collections.

As for your main question:

> C# does var have a strong type?

Yes.  In this case, the *collection itself* does not provide a strong type, so `var` uses `System.Object`.

Answer (score 8):

A `var` declaration in C# is strongly typed but in this case you are dealing with a non-generic collection type in the value `Session`.  This causes C# to choose `object` for the type of `item` and hence you get a later error trying to use `item` in a position that requires a `string`.

For non-generic collections you need to still explicitly type the iterator variable in a `foreach` block

```
foreach(string item in Session) { 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Why did I catch such error?" - because `sb.Append(Session[item] + "]");` is expecting a string  - so you need to cast the `Session[item]` to a string:

```
sb.Append(((string)Session[item]) + "]");
```

as per the MSDN article [How to: Read Values from Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: it's a string... as you see lines upper there is not any error... where Append requires string type... and if you shall make a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop you will see, that it has a string type

Comment: but the collection in Session causes it to be object, hence the requirement for the cast

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `var` is typed statically (i.e. at compile time). The static type of `var`, however, comes from the context, which lets the compiler derive the type of the `var`.

In case of `Session` which implements `IEnumerable`, the only type the compiler can derive is `object`, leading to the error that you describe.

Had `Session` implemented, say, `IEnumerable<string>`, the `var` in the loop would be equivalent to `string`, not to `object`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example it comes down to what type of collection `Session` is. In this case it is a colleciton of objects so the compiler makes `var item` into `object item`.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have indicated, Session's Item property (which is the default indexer) is of type object. That's why you're getting an object from the indexer - that IS its return type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8s0kehy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its because object is a different type. Pretty much like why a derived class is a different from its base class (ex: `class D : B{}`). All class types inherit `Object`, values (struct) I believe do not. They need to be boxed in. The `Session` collection just says it has a bunch of objects and ANYTHING could be in there. The runtime doesn't try to check unless you ask it to (by typecast or is keyword). (More about the compiler below)

The var in that foreach is saying this variable (item) should be whatever type Session enumerator returns. For the most part specifying a different type there is like a typecast.

Just because something is a class or boxes (which means it is an object) doesn't mean the compiler has any idea of what the object actually is. In fact I think the standards suggest if something becomes an object the compiler should not auto convert it even if it knows what type it actually is (perhaps it knows from a few lines above)